# SELECT COUNT(*) expensive query mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have following query:

```
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS `numrows`
    FROM (`phppos_items`)
    WHERE `deleted` =  0
```

explain:

```
mysql> explain SELECT COUNT(*) AS `numrows`
    -> FROM (`phppos_items`)
    -> WHERE `deleted` =  0;
+----+-------------+--------------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table        | type | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | phppos_items | ref  | deleted       | deleted | 4       | const |    1 | Using index |
+----+-------------+--------------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
```

Will this query always be indexed AND fast as the rows in the table grow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Will this query always be indexed AND fast as the rows in the table grow?

Definitely not necessarily. If there are many records and/or the value of deleted is skewed in some way (i.e. it's (nearly) always one particular value, or split 50-50), then the optimiser **may** decide to ignore a given index. Googling "[why does mysql not use an index](https://www.google.ie/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=why%20does%20mysql%20not%20use%20an%20index)" gives 3.5M results

[EDIT]

You said:

> Thank you for your answer. Is there a different type of query I can use to count the number of rows with a WHERE clause?

No -  that's what COUNT() is for. See [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471719994). Basically, you can't get round problems like the one you outline - indexes are frequently helpful, but there's no "magic bullet" that will cope well with all data volumes and profiles.

To see how difficult this problem is, check [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590596366) - that's **> 600 pages** on the **fundamentals** of how an RDBMS decides on the best plan for a query. It is far from a trivial problem!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there a different type of query I can use to count the number of rows with a WHERE clause?

Comment: Check my edit to my original answer.

Comment: I don't think there is ever a case where MySQL will not use the index on `(deleted)` for this query (that just counts rows and wants no other columns retrieved.)

Comment: Sure about that? I would have thought that if the column was massively skewed, maybe an FTS (Full Table Scan) would be more efficient? I'm fairly certain that would be the case with  Oracle? In any case, I didn't say an index would't be used for sure - I was just trying to point out that depending on profiles and volumes of data, optimizers may or may not choose to use an index on a given column, even though it may **appear** logical to do so. The MySQL optimizer is fairly notorious in this regard, and many database professionals continue to be baffled by optimzers on all RDBMS servers.

Comment: You are true for the general case. My comment was meant only for this specific case. No matter how skewed the column is, a full index scan on a 1-column index (+PK columns for InnoDB) will almost certainly be preferred over a full table scan (which has all the columns, plus extra bytes depending on the engine), just because the index is much narrower than the table. (and of course I cannot exclude the possibility that something weird happens and the optimizer chooses the opposite!)